# onclick next page [Select Form]

Tags: html, select

So I'm trying to create a simple select form like the one you see on most websites nowadays. I can't get it to go to the next page when you click the other options.

```
<div class="pages" style="text-align:center; padding-top:10px; ">Navigation:
    <select style="width:300px;">
        <option value="/files/articles/1.html" selected="selected">1.Introduction</option>
        <option value="/files/images/6.html">2. images</option>
        <option value="/files/video/7.html">3. Video</option>
        <option value="/files/news/8.html">4. News</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yJM5c/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this: `<select style="width:300px;">`
To this `<select style="width:300px;" onchange="document.location = this.value">`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This solution was easier for me to fix it than what the other people posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".pages select").change(function() {
            window.location = $(".pages select option:selected").val();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to listen to the onchange event, so that when the value in the select tag changes you grab that value and then navigate to that url like so:

**Javascript**

```
function onChangeNavigate(d) {
  window.top.location = d.value;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="pages" style="text-align:center; padding-top:10px; ">Navigation:
    <select onchange="onChangeNavigate(this)" style="width:300px;">
          <option value="/files/articles/1.html" selected="selected">1. Introduction</option>
           <option value="/files/images/6.html">2. images</option>
           <option value="/files/video/7.html">3. Video</option>
           <option value="/files/news/8.html">4. News</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[MDN Onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XUL/Attribute/onchange)

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div class="pages" style="text-align:center; padding-top:10px; ">Navigation:
                    <select style="width:300px;" onchange="nextpage(this)">
                        <option value="/files/articles/1.html" selected="selected">1. Introduction</option>
                        <option value="/files/images/6.html">2. images</option>
                        <option value="/files/video/7.html">3. Video</option>
                        <option value="/files/news/8.html">4. News</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function nextpage(select){
        window.location = select.value;
    }
    </script>
```